# internal server error 500 occuring after deploying after using getServerSideProps next :js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am trying to host redeploy my website in to vercel i added getServerSideProps in my webiste after that i am getting the following error i dont know what this means and  what should i do to fix it?
in localhost the program is working perfetly
[image]

this  is the  getServerSideProps that i addeed to my index.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi`);
  const data = await res.json();
  // console.log(data);
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

[image]

[image]

if the code i provided is not enough  github.com/vivekkn91/wixten.git here is the git repository note that the webiste has no issue in localhost

his issue occoured after i added getServerSideProps in my index.js and i also found that my inner pages has no issue its wotking perfeclty

[image]

[image]

[image]

i tyred deploying to netlify also.  the home landing page is giving me this page but innerpages are working fine
i am no longer using firebase so its oke to remove all codes based on firebase

i am adding github page for ur refernce feel free to clone the code
https://github.com/vivekkn91/wixten

Comment: The error is from `pages/editor.js:39` - Please post those lines.

Comment: @Ramakay actulay there is no need of editor.js anymore i removed it  the build is now working but i am getting internal servererror 500  but in local hot it is working

Comment: You have posted build logs above for deployment, what do the _function logs_ show once you load up the domain ? https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs

Comment: If you follow along the error, you _maybe_  having issues in your `package.json` - Please post the file.

Comment: Can you share the code for your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

Comment: use `vercel dev` command for local development, not `npm run start`

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A i dont know what u are talking about i deploy my site to vercel thorogh git  i have connected git with vercel so i just have to git  push my site to github and my site autmaticaly do all the build

Comment: https://vercel.com/blog/vercel-dev

Comment: how is this going to help me what change must i make @Mhmdrz_A

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A i did  vercel dev its working fine

Comment: check your node version

Comment: node version is v12.22.9

Comment: i updated now to latest stable version @Mhmdrz_A

Comment: vercel is probably using differnet node verrsion than your local, check what version is vercel setting

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A  i think error is because of getServerSideProps i have updated the question of the error i get after removing some unwanted code

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A i have 14x the most latest version avialable in vercel

Comment: @jisaks `const res = await fetch(`https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi`);` could have returned a non valid json data. e.g: 404 page, error page

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV its working localy when i deploy  i am getting 500 error in vercel and  firebase hostying page that i have added in question in netlify

Comment: @jisaks your api may be returning non json data in production mode. Maybe because of CORS issue, or something like that. Try using axios instead of fetch api and you can see exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

So, I quickly forked your repo to check whether the site is working locally and it is.

Thus, obviously the issue is with how the website being deployd in production on Vercel.
Testing the repo on Vercel is a bit too big of an ask for me, thus I can only give hints about what I see in the error pages, etc.

Thus, what I would suggest is to install the VercelCLI by running the following terminal command if you have npm:

```
$ npm i vercel -g
```

or the one bellow would be better since you are only ussing itfor development purposes - no need to install the package globally with -g

```
$ npm i vercel --save-dev
```

Once installed, login with the vercel login command and provide your email address, which you use for Vercel.

```
$ vercel login me@example.com
```

Once logged in, you can run the vercel dev command to replicate the Vercel deployment environment locally, allowing you to test your Serverless Functions, without requiring you to deploy each time a change is made.

```
$ vercel dev
```

This wont fix the issue itself, but it will be easyer than to constantly re-deploy the app after every code change.

So, what to do next, since I am not going to test the code on Vercel, I can only give you other hints, based on the error messages you have provided.

1. When I ran the repo locally, I got an error in the terminal that the website had an issue with the map function and the /qeustion route. Thus, you should check this url - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error.
2. When I was deploying React.js apps on Digital Cload, I always had to state the engines that my app was ussing. Maybe you have to do something simillar for Vercel since one of the error code images aretalking about the fact that it cant find /server/next:

```
 "name": "wixten",
 "private": true,
 "main": "index.js",
 "engines": {
      "node": "8.11.x",
    "npm": "~1.0.20"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems why this might be happening.

1. For some reason your app (prob. Vercel) needs you to specify the main entry point for your app. I came to this potential conclusion based on your errormessages. You should go to your package.json file in the root and add something like this at the start of the file and then re-deploy.

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",  <------------------ this
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
... rest of content
```

2. The other issue might be that you have accidentally committed the node_modules folder from your App's root folder to your project's Git repo or Vercel server. You should check if that is the case.
3. There might be an issue with your "scripts" in package.json, but I have not used Vercel specifically, so it is hard for me to say.

If you have the Vercel CLI installed on your app... You can use The $vercel dev command to replicate the Vercel deployment environment locally, allowing you to test your Serverless Functions, without requiring you to deploy each time a change is made.

https://vercel.com/blog/vercel-dev#get-started

Comment: i tryed vercel dev but its runiing perfectly in http://localhost:3000  the problem is in prodution i also added the  "main": "index.js",  still same error

Comment: @ ghost  this issur occoured after i added getServerSideProps in my index.js and i also found that my inner pages has no issue its wotking perfeclty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding a postinstall script to my package.json fixed the problem.

What happened in my case was that I needed to run prisma generate command after the postinstall to synch client and server side.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you check your code to see if you have `import next from 'next'` in any part of your code (component/pages/etc)? If you do, try removing this from your code and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Or use your commenting privilege to first delete this post, then ask the question and then base the edited and undeleted answer on the feedback you got.